# ruby win32api & structs (VerQueryValue)

Tags: windows, ruby, winapi

I am trying to call the standard Win32 API functions to get file version info, using the [win32-api library](http://rubyforge.org/projects/win32utils/).

The 3 version.dll functions are GetFileVersionInfoSize, GetFileVersionInfo, and VerQueryValue.  Then I call RtlMoveMemory in kernel32.dll to get a copy of the VS_FIXEDFILEINFO struct (see Microsoft documentation: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997%28VS.85%29.aspx`).

I drew from an example I saw using VB: `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139491`.

My problem is that the data that finally gets returned doesn't seem to match the expected struct, in fact it doesn't even return a consistent value.  I suspect the data is getting mangled at some point, probably in VerQueryValue or RtlMoveMemory.

Here is the code:

```
GetFileVersionInfoSize = Win32::API.new('GetFileVersionInfoSize','PP','I','version.dll')
GetFileVersionInfo = Win32::API.new('GetFileVersionInfo','PIIP','I', 'version.dll')
VerQueryValue = Win32::API.new('VerQueryValue','PPPP','I', 'version.dll')
RtlMoveMemory = Win32::API.new('RtlMoveMemory', 'PPI', 'V', 'kernel32.dll')

buf = [0].pack('L')
version_size = GetFileVersionInfoSize.call(myfile + "\0", buf)
raise Exception.new  if version_size == 0 #TODO

version_info = 0.chr * version_size
version_ok = GetFileVersionInfo.call(file, 0, version_size, version_info)
raise Exception.new if version_ok == 0   #TODO

addr = [0].pack('L')
size = [0].pack('L')
query_ok = VerQueryValue.call(version_info, "\\\0", addr, size)
raise Exception.new if query_ok == 0        #TODO

# note that at this point, size == 4 -- is that right?

fixed_info = Array.new(13,0).pack('L*')
RtlMoveMemory.call(fixed_info, addr, fixed_info.length)

# fixed_info.unpack('L*')  #=> seemingly random data, usually only the first two dwords' worth and the rest 0.
```

Comment: I think I figured it out.. basically VerQueryValue returns a pointer to a pointer (the variable addr above), while RtlMoveMemory wants a pointer, i.e. the long that addr references.  

So I changed the declaration:  

    RtlMoveMemory = Win32::API.new('RtlMoveMemory', 'PLI', 'V', 'kernel32.dll')  

and then calling it:  

    RtlMoveMemory.call(fixed_info, addr.unpack('L')[0], fixed_info.length)

Answer (score 4):

This is the full code I got to work, in case others are looking for such a function.

Returns an array with four parts of product/file version number (i.e., what is called "File Version" in a dll file properties window):

```
def file_version ref, options = {}
  options = {:path => LIBDIR, :extension => 'dll'}.merge(options)
  begin
      file = File.join(ROOT, options[:path],"#{ref}.#{options[:extension]}").gsub(/\//,"\\")
      buf = [0].pack('L')
      version_size = GetFileVersionInfoSize.call(file + "\0", buf)
      raise Exception.new    if version_size == 0 #TODO

      version_info = 0.chr * version_size
      version_ok = GetFileVersionInfo.call(file, 0, version_size, version_info)
      raise Exception.new if version_ok == 0        #TODO

      addr = [0].pack('L')
      size = [0].pack('L')
      query_ok = VerQueryValue.call(version_info, "\\\0", addr, size)
      raise Exception.new if query_ok == 0        #TODO

      fixed_info = Array.new(18,0).pack('LSSSSSSSSSSLLLLLLL')
      RtlMoveMemory.call(fixed_info, addr.unpack('L')[0], fixed_info.length)

      fixed_info.unpack('LSSSSSSSSSSLLLLLLL')[5..8].reverse

  rescue
        []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224681/3730446 isn't strictly correct: the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct contains separate `FileVersion` and `ProductVersion`.  That code returns a version number consisting of the two more-significant components of the `ProductVersion` and the two less-significant components of the `FileVersion`. Most times I've seen, that wouldn't matter because both `Product-` and `FileVersion` have the same value, but you never know what you might encounter in the wild.

We can see this by comparing the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx and the format string we're using to pack and unpack the buffer:

```
typedef struct tagVS_FIXEDFILEINFO {
    DWORD dwSignature;        //  0: L
    DWORD dwStrucVersion;     //  1: S
                              //  2: S
    DWORD dwFileVersionMS;    //  3: S
                              //  4: S
    DWORD dwFileVersionLS;    //  5: S
                              //  6: S
    DWORD dwProductVersionMS; //  7: S
                              //  8: S
    DWORD dwProductVersionLS; //  9: S
                              // 10: S
    DWORD dwFileFlagsMask;    // 11: L
    DWORD dwFileFlags;        // 12: L
    DWORD dwFileOS;           // 13: L
    DWORD dwFileType;         // 14: L
    DWORD dwFileSubtype;      // 15: L
    DWORD dwFileDateMS;       // 16: L
    DWORD dwFileDateLS;       // 17: L
} VS_FIXEDFILEINFO;
```

Subscripts 5 to 8, then, consists of `dwFileVersionLS` and `dwProductVersionMS`. Getting `FileVersion` and `ProductVersion` correctly would look like this:

```
info = fixed_info.unpack('LSSSSSSSSSSLLLLLLL')
file_version = [ info[4], info[3], info[6], info[5] ]
product_version = [ info[8], info[7], info[10], info[9] ]
```